# Proof : Abel's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

[image]**How to Prove Abel's Theorem using Cauchy’s criterion for series and Abel’s formula** ?

Abel's Theorem

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two sequences of real numbers such that

• $(a_n)$ is non-increasing and tends to $0$,

• There exists $M \in R$ such that, for any $n \in N$, $| \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k| \leq M.$
Then the series $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converges

While Cauchy's criterion for series -

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $  converges if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there is a positive integer N such that if m > n > N then $| \sum_{j=n}^{m} a_n | < \epsilon $

How can I prove the above using these both.

Answer (score 1):

You also need $a_n>0$ for this to work, so I'll assume it from now on.

Let $$B_n=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k$$

Then
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{m} a_k b_k & = \sum_{k=n}^m a_k (B_k-B_{k-1})  \\
& = \sum_{k=n}^m a_k B_k - \sum_{k=n}^m a_k B_{k-1} \\
& = \sum_{k=n}^m a_k B_k - \sum_{k=n-1}^{m-1} a_{k+1} B_k \\
& = a_m B_m - a_nB_{n-1} +\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}(a_k - a_{k+1})B_k
\end{align}$$

So
$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{m} a_k b_k\right| & \leq a_m |B_m| + a_n |B_{n-1}| + \sum_{k=n}^{m-1} (a_k-a_{k+1})|B_k| \\
& \leq M(a_m + a_n + a_n - a_m) \\
& \leq 2M a_n
\end{align}$$

Since $a_n$ tends to $0$, then our series satisfies the Cauchy Criterion.

Comment: But How Abel's Theorem Is proved, I think you proved abel's  formula instead of theorem.. Abel's theorem says that $\sum a_n b_n $ converges if 1.) $a_n$ tends to $0$ and 2.) $b_n$ converges

Comment: Maybe I've confused the two. But what you've mentioned is definitely not Abel's theorem. Just because $a_n$ tends to $0$ and $b_n$ converges doesn't mean that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges. For example: $a_n=\frac1n$, $b_n=1$.

Comment: I added one image to the question. HAve a look on Abel's theorem. And it is to be proved using cauchy criterion and abel's formula

Comment: Isn't that what I've proven? The series $\sum a_n b_n$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion, so it must be convergent.